# how to manipulate line breaks in php?

Tags: php, line-breaks

I wanted to know if there's a way to manipulate line breaks within PHP. Like, to explicitly tell what kind of line break to select (LF, CRLF...) for using in an `explode()` function for instance.

it would be something like that:

```
$rows = explode('<LF>', $list);
//<LF> here would be the line break
```

anyone can help? thanks (:

Comment: sure, manual helps: http://php.net/types.string

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*LF* and *CR* are just abbreviations for the characters with the code point 0x0A (*LINE FEED*) and 0x0D (*CARRIAGE RETURN*) in ASCII. You can either write them literally or use appropriate escape sequences:

```
"\x0A" "\n"  // LF
"\x0D" "\r"  // CR
```

Remember using the [double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) as [single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) do only know the escape sequences `\\` and `\'`.

*CRLF* would then just be the concatenation of both characters. So:

```
$rows = explode("\r\n", $list);
```

If you want to split at both CR *and* LF you can do a split using a regular expression:

```
$rows = preg_split("/[\r\n]/", $list);
```

And to skip empty lines (i.e. sequences of more than just one line break characters):

```
$rows = preg_split("/[\r\n]+/", $list);
```

Comment: thank you so much! i even tried `\n` but i dinn't know of this issue with the single quotes :D

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: Single and double quoted strings are handled differently in PHP. Both are to declare strings but single quoted strings are some kind of “more literally” or “more raw” than double quoted strings as they support less escape sequences (only the two mentioned).

Comment: i knew some differents like the way they handle variables inside of it. but this onde was obscure to me. thanks again ^^

Answer (score 3):

Some possibilities I can think of, depending on your needs:

- Pick an EOL style and specify the exact character(s): `"\r\n"`
- Choose the EOL of the platform PHP runs on and use the `PHP_EOL` constant
- Use regular expressions: `preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', ...)`
- Use a function that can autodetect line endings: `file()`
- Normalize the input string before exploding:

  ```php
  $text = strtr($text, array(
      "\r\n" => PHP_EOL,
      "\r" => PHP_EOL,
      "\n" => PHP_EOL,
  ));
  ```